# Differential equation with $\sqrt{1-\cos(f)}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm currently trying to solve the differential equation
$$
\sqrt{2} a \cdot \sqrt{1 - \cos(f)} = f'
$$
where $a$ is a constant and I can freely choose $f(0)$ to simplify the solution and calculation.

I tried $\sqrt{1-\cos(x)} = \sqrt{2} | \sin(x/2) |$ and I know $\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x} \ln |\tan(x)| = 2/\sin(2x)$ but when I use separation of variables to get
$$
\begin{align*}
&&\sqrt{2} a \cdot \sqrt{1 - \cos(f)} &= f'\\
\Rightarrow
&&2 a \cdot |\sin(f/2)| &= f'\\
\Rightarrow
&&2a x &= \int\limits_{f(0)}^{f(x)} \frac{1}{|\sin(u/2)|} \ \mathrm{d}u\\
\Rightarrow
&&a x &= \int\limits_{f(0)/4}^{f(x)/4} \frac{2}{|\sin(2v)|} \ \mathrm{d}v
\end{align*}
$$
I don't know what to do with the absolute value. The exercise tells me the solution is
$$
f(x) =
4 \arctan
\left(
e^{a x}
\right)
$$

which I also get for $f(0) = \pi$ and if I ignore the absolute value and just assume that we are not integrating over any poles.

Is it a poorly stated exercise with a solution that's only true under certain assumptions or am I missing something?

Comment: in line 2 :  $\sqrt{1-cos(f)}=\sqrt{2} |sin(\frac{f}{2})|$ not $ |sin(\frac{x}{2})|$

Comment: oh that was a typo. But it doesn't change anything